# Orchard CMS - Can Permissions Be Set for a Single Content Item Instance Such as a Custom Form

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

In Orchard CMS I know that permissions can be set for content types. What is the suggested way to set permissions on single instances of content items. In particular, I would like to use the custom forms module to create  multiple custom forms where some are only available to authenticated users while others are available to anonymous users. I am fine with creating a custom module for this but would like to have at least a general idea of what would is involved with building more granular permissions at the content item level. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with the built-in Content Item Permissions feature. This enables you to attach the Content Permissions content part to your content types, which will add a set of checkboxes to the editor to customize the accessibility of each content item of that type.

Comment: Is the content item permissions feature documented anywhere? Having trouble finding it.

Comment: Not that I know of. Do you have any trouble using it?

Comment: I found the documentation. Was more straightforward than I expected. Thanks.

Comment: @bingles could you please post where you found the documentation on the Content Item Permissions? I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: The only documentation I can find is at the end of this page http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-permissions#OrchardContentPermissions which doesn't really provide any details, but the answer really is as simple as mentioned by Benedek. I went ahead and answered the question with some screenshots for a little more detail.

Answer (score 17):

I was never really able to find any detailed documentation on this so here is a summary of what is involved:

1) Under "Modules" section Enable "Content Item Permissions" feature

[image: Enable Content Item Permissions Feature]

2) Under "Content Definition" find the content type you want to add permissions to and click "Edit"

[image]

3) Attach the "Content Permissions" part to your content type

[image: Content Permissions Part]

4) After adding the part you can manage the permission settings

[image]